# Why are my global variables not updating after i call my functions?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, global-variables

I created a couple of functions which load a dataset from github and then combines it. This part of the code works correctly. My problem arises when I run the combine function for a second time.

What I tried when testing if my functions work as intended.

```
loadDataset("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AAF108/ml/master/test3")
print (dataset)
combine({"data": [{"room_temperature": 20, "light_intensity": 
511,"humidity": 50}]})
print(combinedData)
```

the URL in loadDataset is this:

```
{"data": [{"room_temperature": 20, "light_intensity": 511,"humidity": 50}]}
```

When I run this part I get (which is what I expected to get):

```
   humidity  light_intensity  room_temperature
0        50              511                20


   humidity  light_intensity  room_temperature
0        50              511                20
0        50              511                20
```

Below is the code for the functions I made:

```
def loadDataset(url):
    global dataset
    dataset = pd.read_json(url)

def combine(obj):
    global combinedData

    json= obj

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(json["data"])

    combinedData = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

My problem arises when I do this:

```
loadDataset("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AAF108/ml/master/test3")
print (dataset)
combine({"data": [{"room_temperature": 20, "light_intensity": 
511,"humidity": 50}]})
print(combinedData)
combine({"data": [{"room_temperature": 20, "light_intensity": 
511,"humidity": 50}]})
print(combinedData)
```

What I Expect:

```
   humidity  light_intensity  room_temperature
0        50              511                20


   humidity  light_intensity  room_temperature
0        50              511                20
0        50              511                20
0        50              511                20
```

What I get instead:

```
   humidity  light_intensity  room_temperature
0        50              511                20


   humidity  light_intensity  room_temperature
0        50              511                20
0        50              511                20
```

I'm not sure why my combineData is not updating.

Comment: It looks like it does update, just not as much as you expect. You called `print(combinedData)` twice, and got a longer result in the second `print`. It could be helpful to double-check your `combine` function.

Comment: @Kevin but if it worked correctly woouldnt i get 3 rows since i am combining it twice onto my original dataframe with 1 row?

Comment: I think you may want to check the content of `df1` and `df2` with 2 `print` in your `combine` function.

Comment: @A0sXc950 are you running your code as a script or in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @gmdsi am running everything on pycharm

Comment: Why do you want global variables in the first place?

Comment: @gmds I want to be able to use combinedData in another function which calculates the averages for each column

Comment: @A0sXc950 for that reason, you do not really need global variable (in my opinion, try to avoid global variables as much as you can). Just simply remove `global combinedData`, add `return combinedData` in your `combine` function. And in your main script, use `combinedData = combine(...)` instead of `combine(...)`. In the other function that needs `combinedData`, just pass your global `combinedData` to that function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>That's not how `global` works. Rather, it "imports" the *name* `combinedData` into your function as a local variable that refers to the globally defined object.</s>

So, therefore, when you run `combinedData = pd.concat([df1, df2])`, you are assigning the result of `pd.concat([df1, df2])` to the *local* variable `combinedData`. This change is obviously not visible in the global scope.

You should avoid using global variables in this way, and instead pass objects as arguments.

If you *really* want to do this, though...you can do something like this (edit: this actually wouldn't work because `pd.append` doesn't work inplace):

```
combinedData = pd.DataFrame()

def combine(obj):
    global combinedData

    json = obj

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(json["data"])

    combinedData.append(pd.concat([df1, df2]))
```

Thanks to a comment, I did some more testing, and I found the *real* reason OP's code doesn't work: the runtime environment.

If you run this code as a *script*, then it does modify the global variable `combinedData`. However, if you run it in a *Jupyter notebook*, then it doesn't.

Comment: `global combinedData` does allow you to re-assign a new value to the global `combinedData`, and this is visible in the global scope. I just made a simple script to check this.

Comment: now when i try to print combinedData i get empty dataframes. Am i trying to print global variables incorrectly?

Comment: @A0sXc950 Actually, I made a mistake; that would not work, either.

Comment: @Kevin Apparently, `global` behaves differently in a Jupyter notebook, as compared to in a script. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks for the headsup!